# Android Studio emulator not updating my changes

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation

I am writing a database app in Android Studio and I have changed the design layout so that it has a few text boxes and an input button. I have done all the code for it and saved it all multiple times but when I run the emulator of my app it is still not showing my design I have done and is still just showing the "Hello World" default text box you get when you first make a new app. Can anyone tell me why the emulator is not updating when I save? thanks

Comment: check if you are working on the right XML file haha

Comment: For me it was confusing to have different XML files for different API versions, and as @Elyes guest I was working on wrong file.

Answer (score 6):

There are some cases that the emulator gets corrupt.
It will not behave properly and update your app.
If you are sure that your app complies with no errors and Studio installs it on the emulator.

Go to tools->AVD Manager.
Right click on the device you are using and select **wipe data**.

This will, of course, delete all the device data.
So if there is nothing important there it should help.

[image: AVD MANAGER]

Answer (score 2):

Some layout changes do not cause the app to be rebuilt when it is run through RUN. Try to clear the app and then run it, if it does not work, `Clear` > `Rebuild` > `Run`.

If this works for you, add these tasks to the automatic tasks whenever the run is used.

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1** : Open developer mode on android emulator with Fn+CMD+M (keys For mac users)

[image]

**Step 2** : press **Enable Live Reload** Or **Disable Live Reload**

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue and it worked for me:
`Run`> `Apply code changes and restart activity`

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this problem. The reason it doesn't update the code is because an error exists in your code. To view the updated app, fix the error in your code and then rebuild the solution. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Front end ui changes may not be reflecting on your emulator.
Try a clean all then build.

Visual Studio for Mac

build -> clean all
builld -> rebuild all

In my case I was updating the wrong stack.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem but I am using "Flutter" in "IntelliJ", I found the solution by this way:
Choose from the top bar in IntelliJ: Run >> Flutter Hot Restart (All Devices) - Crtl +  Alt + Shift + \

Now the Android Emulator updates the new code, otherwise a lot of time it's stuck and loads the old code & not updating the new one.

Note: Sometimes you need to Run the app again if the choice of "Flutter Hot Restart (All Devices)" is disabled, this is maybe because it's lost connection.

Answer (score 0):

I use Android Studio Bumblebee 21.1.1 | Patch 3 on a Jetpack Compose project, the exact same problem, mostly happens to me after using many times the clean build command on terminal and after that any change on the code doesn't affect emulator's output. What worked for me was to rebuild after the command. If it doesn't work for you, try to go to your C:\Users[User_Name].android\avd find the folder of the emulator that you are using and delete cache.img and cache.img.qcow2 files, after that launch emulator again.